# Can't load saved template in Grapesjs

Tags: templates, grapesjs

Can't load saved template in Grapesjs[image]

Answer (score 0):

first check your storeManager settings in the options you passed while initialising grapesjs.
if you haven't provided any then refer documentation and add one and if failed to so let me know.
second thing if you pass your html & css while initialising grapesjs,then it will load passed template.

Comment: it has been sorted out.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you have loaded the HTML into DOM
2. initialize the grapesJS component

For example:

```
 <body>
 <div id="gjs"></div>
 </body>


loadTemplate(
 function(){loadEditor();}
);        


function loadTemplate(callback){
 var component = angular.element('#gjs');
 component.append(yourHTMLtemplate);
 ...

 if(callback) callback();

}

function loadEditor(){
 $scope.editor = grapesjs.init({
 container: '#gjs',

 ...

}
```